# Making a PUT without refreshing the page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a blade form in Laravel

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/'.$cpe_mac.'/device/'.$device_mac.'/update', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' =>'form','method' => 'PUT')) !!}

        <span class="pull-left">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Downlink </p>
                <select type="text" class="form-control" name="max_down" >
                    @foreach ($rate_limit as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{$value or ''}}">{{$value or ''}} Kbps</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Uplink</p>
                <select type="text" class="form-control" name="max_up" >
                    @foreach ($rate_limit as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{$value or ''}}">{{$value or ''}} Kbps</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </span><br>


        {!! Form::hidden('cpe_mac', $cpe_mac)!!}
        {!! Form::hidden('device_mac', $device_mac)!!}



        <span class="pull-right">
            <button class="saveRateLimitBTN btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
        </span>


{!! Form::close();!!}
```

I want to be make a Ajax HTTP PUT without refresh my page.
How should my form look like ?

Right now, it keep redirecting me to `url/update`, and then redirecting it back.

How do I send all those data to my controller in the background ?

Any hints / suggestion on this will be a huge helps !

Comment: You add a button that will call a function when clicked (instead of submitting the form). The function will make an AJAX call. In the call you can decide what you want to do with SUCCESS and FAILURE scenarios.

Comment: Sure, I'll start from that then. But do I sent value from the form to my controller in Laravel. I hope you don't mind elaborate that a bit more.

Comment: This is more of a javascript question on how to populate the values and send the right PUT request to the server. On laravel server side, you will need to process the request. On the browser, you can either populate the values once the button is clicked or you can use data binding.

Comment: (I don't think browsers will make PUT requests, but `Form` should have added an `_action` element in the form automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually I place my forms in a modal popup with a data-dismiss button that will simply close after you hit submit and run everything in the background.

For your case, after hitting submit without refreshing the page after hitting the submit button would seem a bit odd wouldn't it?

However here's a bit of jQuery to get you going either way:

```
$("#mySubmitButton").on('click', function(event){

    var form = '#myForm';

  $.post($(form).attr('action'),$(form).serialize());

});
```

Add an ID to your form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/'.$cpe_mac.'/device/'.$device_mac.'/update', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' =>'form','method' => 'PUT', 'id' => 'myForm')) !!}
```

Add an ID to your button:

```
<button id="mySubmitButton" class="saveRateLimitBTN btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
```

Add a TYPE to your button (to prevent it from submitting/refreshing);

```
<button type="button" id="mySubmitButton" class="saveRateLimitBTN btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
```

If your routes are properly setup to lead to your controller then all your form input variables are now accessible via $request or Input:

```
public function processForm(Request $request)
{
    $variable1 = $request->input('myforminputname1');
    $variable2 = $request->input('myforminputname2');

    // Or get it through Input
    $variable1 = \Input::get('myforminputname1');
    $variable2 = \Input::get('myforminputname2');
}
```

Comment: How do I access my form data in my controller ?

Comment: You would access it like a regular if it was done with refreshing. I updated my answer.